# How to use Nvidia GEForce 7600 GT for display with 1080TI for only CUDA/Deep Learning

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, multiple-monitors, cuda

I am currently running a Ubuntu 18.04 machine with two GPUs on the motherboard. One is a NVIDIA GEForce 7600 GT, and another is the NVIDIA GEForce 1080 TI.

I would like to use the 1080 TI with the CUDA 10.0, and cudnn to run deep learning, while simultaneously using the NVIDIA GEForce 7600 GT for only display purposes. I am wondering what the process I should go about to do this and what are some things I should take into account that are different from just a straight installation/setup of CUDA/cudnn.

I am looking for discrete steps to take, as I know how to install CUDA/cudnn, but not sure if there should be a specific order in which I do things now to make sure the 1080ti is only used for deep learning, and the other is only used for display.

I have tried plugging in a monitor to both GPUs, but only the 1080ti is showing its monitor right now.

Thank you.